# Self linked renationship to schema

Tags: erd

How do I convert this self linked relationship to schema?

[self relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwYtX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If one course has ATMOST ONE prerequisite.

```sql
CREATE TABLE course_catalog (
    course_no <type> PRIMARY KEY,
    ... other fields
    prerequisite_course_no <type same as course_no>,
    FOREIGN KEY(prerequisite_course_no) REFERENCES course_catalog(course_no)
)
```

keep prerequisite_course_no field null if there are no prerequisites.

If one course can have MANY prerequisites.

```sql
CREATE TABLE course_catalog (
    course_no <type> PRIMARY KEY,
    ... other fields
);
CREATE TABLE course_prerequisites (
    course_no <type>,
    prerequisite_course_no <type same as course_no>,
    PRIMARY KEY(course_no,prerequisite_course_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(prerequisite_course_no) REFERENCES course_catalog(course_no),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_no) REFERENCES course_catalog(course_no)
)
```